# Date picker month selection animation

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

Can you set the datepicker to have no animation when selecting the month?  The scroll animation is a bit distracting and slow.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the Calendar component doesn't expose any animation configuration. I am afraid that there is no easy way to disable scroll animation.

I would suggest you post your request in the Kendo UserVoice portal:

http://kendoui-feedback.telerik.com/forums/555517-kendo-ui-for-angular-feedback

Thus more people could cast their vote for this functionality.